# Git .git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

Tags: git, centos, bitbucket

I'm getting a strange problem in my CentOS server. My repositories are hosted on Bitbucket, and they were working fine until yesterday.

Here is the problem. I get the following error when I try to push or pull from my CentOS terminal.

```
fatal: https://[url]/[repo-name].git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

I can manage the same repositories using [SourceTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlassian#Acquisitions_and_product_announcements) on my Windows computer without a problem. But I need to be able to manage them using the terminal as well.

How do I get over this problem?

The Git version on my server is 1.8.2.1, and it was working fine until yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Bitbucket just changed their IP address today. Are you perhaps having issues with your firewalls?

Here's the [Bitbucket help site on the topic](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall-343343385.html).

Comment: Thank you Daphoa, You are right. I tried it again after seeing your reply. It works fine now.  I must have got the error during the IP migration period.