# fatal: .git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

Tags: git, github

I have a Git repository hosted at Assembla for which I'm trying to perform:

```
git push -u origin master
```

I'm getting the following error over and over again:

```
fatal: https://[url]/[repo-name].git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

I've tried the answer here without any success: [Git .git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302709/git-git-info-refs-not-valid-is-this-a-git-repository)

When I use:

```
git status
```

I get:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: If you run `git remote show origin`, do you see what you expect for the URL under Fetch and Push URLs? Should be something like git@git.assembla.com:[REPO-NAME].git

Comment: you're right the URL wasnt typed correctly, thanks a lot!

Comment: I had a similar error, however, in my situation it was cause by my cntlm proxy configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
git remote show origin
```

showed that the remote repository I tried to push to wasn't correct.

After fixing that with:

```
git remote set-url origin [REPO-URL]
```

the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure the proxy is set correctly for Git if you're behind a proxy!

```
git config --global http.proxy <proxyserver>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Safari, input and jump to your Git repository URL again. systerm will let you authorization. Use the Git account and password again, then open your Xcode, and you can pull smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly that error message (I am still ignoring the cause) and I solved it in a different but simple way:

```
git fetch --all
```

It is a solution suggested among many others [here](https://git.seveas.net/repairing-and-recovering-broken-git-repositories.html).

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Email using Tortoise-Git Settings then i got same error...

I updated my Git user/pass in WindowsCredentials Manager and error gone, now it works.