# Getting fatal error: .git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git repo hosted at AWS whom im trying to preform:

```
git push -u origin master
```

I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: http://[URL]/[Repo-Name].git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?
```

Ive tried the answer here without any success: 
[Git .git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302709/git-git-info-refs-not-valid-is-this-a-git-repository)

[fatal: .git/info/refs not valid: is this a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43049278/fatal-git-info-refs-not-valid-is-this-a-git-repository)

What will be the possible solutions over this error?

When I am using

```
git remote -v
```

I am getting:

```
origin  http://[URL]/test1.git (fetch)
origin  http://[URL]/test1.git (push)
```

Comment: Need more information. Did anything happen the last time to tried to push to remote? Did you lose Internet connectivity mid-push? Also, add the output of `git remote -v`. Maybe the URLs differ.

Comment: I have added the o/p of git remote -v. where test1 is repo name and this is the first time I am pushing into git. Internet connectivity is fine.

Answer (score 1):

The answers you linked refer to a change in the URL. Generally it happens on locally hosted servers such as GitLab that the ports displayed differ. You might want to check what your port is, it may not be the default port(80).

Comment: The port I am using that is 80 is correct dont know if any other mistake I am doing

Answer (score 0):

Another reason that causes this error could be missing access rights for the user which tries to connect to the repository. In gitlab, make sure that the user is a *member* of the repository and is registered as *Developer*.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your remote git repository is local or remote and if you are going through a Proxy or not.

For local repo you should bypass the proxy. For example, to bypass proxy for your repo at "origin" you can use this:

```
git config --add remote.origin proxy ""
```

This will bypass proxy, if you are inside a corporate firewall and you should not get this error.

Comment: poster said "hosted at AWS" [https://aws.amazon.com/] .. so .. not inside LAN, or there'd be a team of amazon IT to ask instead of us ;-)